# Using Invoke-Command to run Start-Process in an elevated session

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, elevated-privileges

As a precursor to running an installation file on several remote servers, I need to update the Powershell setting `MaxMemoryPerShellMB`. This requires running a PS session as Administrator on the remote server. I have been trying to run `Invoke-Command` which then runs a ScriptBlock consisting of a `Start-Process` command which includes the `-Verb RunAs` parameter. Nothing seems to work, however.

I have tried with various quoting schemes, single, double, triple, but nothing seems to work.

I've tried running the `Start-Process` from an `Enter-PSSession`, with the same results.

Following is the code I'm testing now:

```
$creds = Get-Credential -Username 'DOMAIN\userID' -Message "Enter Username and Password to access the remote servers."

$ScriptBlock = {
    Start-Process -FilePath Powershell.exe -ArgumentList """Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 1024""" -Verb RunAs -Wait 
}
Invoke-Command -ComputerName testsvr01 -Credential $creds -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
```

I should be able to RDP to the remote server and run `Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell` and have it show the updated value, but the value isn't changed.

When running the code it pauses for a second when the `Invoke-Command` runs, but other than that, there is no feedback in Powershell.

On the remote server I see the following two Kerberos errors in the System Event log.

`0x19 KDC_ERR_PREAUTH_REQUIRED`,

`0xd  KDC_ERR_BADOPTION`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> powershell.exe -?
...
EXAMPLES
...
PowerShell -Command "& {Get-EventLog -LogName security}"

-Command
...
 To write a string that runs a Windows PowerShell command, use the format:
    "& {<command>}"
where the quotation marks indicate a string and the invoke operator (&)
causes the command to be executed.
```

So you could try to call `Set-Item` in the following way:

```
$ScriptBlock = {
    Start-Process -FilePath Powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-Command"," &{ Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 1024 }" -Verb RunAs -Wait -PassThru
}
$process = Invoke-Command -ComputerName testsvr01 -Credential $creds -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
$process.ExitCode
```

I'm also returning a process object via `-PassThru` on which you might check the `ExitCode``

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your clarification on the syntax. That helped. 

Unfortunately it didn't solve my issue. To add some detail, I'm running this from a W2K16 server trying to execute the command on a W2K8 R2 server. I spent hours researching the kerberos issues with nothing to show for it. 

I finally tried a different W2K8 server and it worked after running `Enable-PSRemoting` on it. After checking, I found that this server had been upgraded to Powershell 5.1. 
I went back to my original server, upgraded it to 5.1, re-ran `Enable-PSRemoting` and was finally able to run the update.

Thanks

Comment: I'd up vote you, but apparently I don't have the reputation yet. Marked you as the answer, though.