# Powershell throws error with Get-ADPrincipleGroup

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Hoping someone maybe able to help with the below error i get when running a powershell script i created. It worked before fine no issues.

"The Operation being Requested was not performed because the user has not been authenticated."

So the account is permissoned fine and i can run various commands fine in PS. The script works fine on another users machine no issues. I can get around the error with `-ResourceContextServer` parameter but this is not ideal as this is part of a gui which will look at another domain on top of Domain A. So i use that it will not search Domain B when prompted.

Google has given me little insight although i found on thing which i tried and it worked for a period then i get the same again

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues.Add('Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership:Server',"$((Get-ADDomain).PDCEmulator)")
```

The command that is causing the issues is `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` running in PS on it own i get the same. Running other commands is fine and no issues.

Anyone else seen this and have solution. It is making things hard when i want to update the script and test it.

Thanks

Comment: Are you running as admin or is uac disabled?

Comment: Some confirmation but no solution. I can reproduce this as a permissioned users, Adm on the server (lesser priveledged account) with UAC disabled.  I get the error even when Imanually specifying `-Server` and even when directing to a non-PDCe, regardless of the default for `-Server`. With my Dom Adm account, I can reproduce when specified through `$PSDefaultParameterValues` and manually specifying `-Server`, but not when manually specifying a non-PDCe server. It doesn't seem to happen with other AD cmdlets either.

Comment: UAC is enabled. Its same when running as admin and not. 

@Steven yes other AD commands are fine just this one. Its a weird one. I thought adding the defaul parms fixed it but its come back... Not sure why. Other users are fine and can run the script fine. Seems like some bug looking on google but nothing definitive. I don't really want to specify the `-ResourceContextServer ` for this as it can be used via a button to pull from another domain. 
only other thing i can think of thats changed was i added some extra logging and error abilities but tests on other machines work.

Comment: might be a red herring, but you say you're trying to run `Get-ADPrincipleGroupMembership`, but it's `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`

Comment: I think you might be also be after something more like `'(Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Server $servername)'` instead of `'Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership:Server'`

Comment: @Dallas First point was a typo :) I changed that. 

I will try with the second. But that will restrict to one domain. This will work with two domains so the above when testing allowed to both to work. For some reason i keep getting that error on and off. After a few days its fine for a few then reverts. The only link i can find is when it changes domains then reverts it produces that. Other users who tested don't get this.

Answer (score 1):

This is one method to get it to work.  If you're requesting credentials at some point, you could use the same `$Creds` variable multiple times, and this does work

```
$username = TheUserToFindGroupd
$OperatorUsername = YourOperatorOrScriptUsername
$Creds = Get-Credential -Credential $OperatorUsername
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $username -Credential $Creds | Get-ADGroup -Properties * | select name
```

It'll authenticate and run against the currently connected DC (I've tried it, where specifying -server for DC1 works, but DC2 and DC3 don't)

Two alternative ways, which I probably prefer anyway, get the MemberOf field from the Get-ADUser.  In my testing, it gets all groups, apart from `Domain Users`.

```
Get-ADUser $username -Properties MemberOf | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | Select-Object Name
```

and

```
foreach ($Group in (Get-ADUser $username -Properties MemberOf | Select -ExpandProperty MemberOf)) { write-host ($Group.Split(",")[0]).Split("=")[1] }
```

They are both faster than `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`, but the first is a lot cleaner (even if it will be more intensive on the DC).

Comment: FYI, your script defines $OperatorUser, but uses $OperatorUsername.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens if you have disabled account delegation on your admin account which is a security best practice. It means your user account credentials cannot be forwarded to a second computer. When I run
`Set-Aduser joe.bloggs -accountnotdelegated $false`
Then the Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership cmd works fine. If set to false then I get the user not authenticated error.
You got the workaround is to use ResourceContextServer

Answer (score 0):

We got this working by repassing the credential with the call to `Get-AdPrincipalGroupMembership`.  It's a bit painful to recredential every time, but if you cache the credential it makes it easier.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (30.08.22):
Following from [2ps solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72449807/3789665), explicitly run powershell as your domain account (even if already logged in with it..) and run Get-AdPrincipalGroupMembership from there... Disabling delegation made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had been logged on for more than 2 days so my authentication was expired. Logging out and back in solved it.

Answer (score 0):

The Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership cmdlet gets the Active Directory groups that have a specified user, computer, group, or service account as a member

Use this instead, it searches the one users groupmembership instead of searching the groups for the user:

## Retrieve user's group memberships

```
    $userGroups = Get-ADUser -Identity $username -Properties MemberOf | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf
    $groupMembers = $userGroups | ForEach-Object { (Get-ADGroup $_).Name }
```